# Importing data to influx DB with DDL/DML & setting retention policy

Tags: influxdb

I have data in a text file as below...

```
 DML
 CONTEXT-DATABASE: import
 CONTEXT-RETENTION-POLICY: oneyear

FO,type=FreshOrders avg_FreshOrders=1479.0840707964599,p95_FreshOrders=2589,FreshOrders=226 1593648000000
FO,type=FreshOrders avg_FreshOrders=2242.86170212766,p95_FreshOrders=5622,FreshOrders=188 1593475200000
FO,type=FreshOrders avg_FreshOrders=1682.3375,p95_FreshOrders=2738,FreshOrders=160 1593734400000
```

I placed this text file in a folder called data inside influxDB. My requirement is to import last 3 lines of data into influx DB. I am navigating into influxDB folder `C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\influxdb-1.8.0_windows_amd64\influxdb-1.8.0-1` and running the below command in command prompt to import it

```
influx -import -path=C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\influxdb-1.8.0_windows_amd64\influxdb-1.8.0-1\data\import.txt -precision=ns
```

But data is not getting imported and getting below error. Can someone please help me in resolving this issue?

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\influxdb-1.8.0_windows_amd64\influxdb-1.8.0-1>influx -import -path=C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\influxdb-1.8.0_windows_amd64\influxdb-1.8.0-1\data\import.txt -precision=s
2020/07/13 16:34:25 error: error parsing query: found DML, expected SELECT, DELETE, SHOW, CREATE, DROP, EXPLAIN, GRANT, REVOKE, ALTER, SET, KILL at line 1, char 1
2020/07/13 16:34:25 error: error parsing query: found CONTEXT, expected SELECT, DELETE, SHOW, CREATE, DROP, EXPLAIN, GRANT, REVOKE, ALTER, SET, KILL at line 1, char 1
2020/07/13 16:34:25 error: error parsing query: found CONTEXT, expected SELECT, DELETE, SHOW, CREATE, DROP, EXPLAIN, GRANT, REVOKE, ALTER, SET, KILL at line 1, char 1
2020/07/13 16:34:25 error: error parsing query: found FO, expected SELECT, DELETE, SHOW, CREATE, DROP, EXPLAIN, GRANT, REVOKE, ALTER, SET, KILL at line 1, char 1
2020/07/13 16:34:25 error: error parsing query: found FO, expected SELECT, DELETE, SHOW, CREATE, DROP, EXPLAIN, GRANT, REVOKE, ALTER, SET, KILL at line 1, char 1
2020/07/13 16:34:25 error: error parsing query: found FO, expected SELECT, DELETE, SHOW, CREATE, DROP, EXPLAIN, GRANT, REVOKE, ALTER, SET, KILL at line 1, char 1
```

Comment: This clearly seems like your file content is not correctly formatted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the content of your file as below:

```
# DML
# CONTEXT-DATABASE: import
# CONTEXT-RETENTION-POLICY: oneyear

FO,type=FreshOrders avg_FreshOrders=1479.0840707964599,p95_FreshOrders=2589,FreshOrders=226 1593648000000
FO,type=FreshOrders avg_FreshOrders=2242.86170212766,p95_FreshOrders=5622,FreshOrders=188 1593475200000
FO,type=FreshOrders avg_FreshOrders=1682.3375,p95_FreshOrders=2738,FreshOrders=160 1593734400000
```

Comment: I tried by updating the format as suggested by you, now i am getting below errors  `[ec2-user@ip-172-31-19-10 bin]$ ./influx -import -path=/home/ec2-user/data/import.txt -precision=ns
2020/07/14 03:02:54 error writing batch:  {"error":"retention policy not found: oneyear"}

FO,type=FreshOrders avg_FreshOrders=2242.86170212766,p95_FreshOrders=5622,FreshOrders=188 1593475200000

ERROR: 2 points were not inserted
`

Comment: Also can i know why do we need to comment these steps?  `# DML
# CONTEXT-DATABASE: import
# CONTEXT-RETENTION-POLICY: oneyear`

Comment: Did you ran the DDL commands before running this?
# DDL
CREATE DATABASE import
CREATE RETENTION POLICY oneyear ON import DURATION 365d REPLICATION 1

Comment: With DDL i executed the command and i could see below result  `[ec2-user@ip-172-31-19-10 bin]$ ./influx -import -path=/home/ec2-user/data/import.txt -precision=ns
2020/07/15 03:08:48 Processed 1 commands
2020/07/15 03:08:48 Processed 3 inserts
2020/07/15 03:08:48 Failed 0 inserts`

Comment: which means data is inserted but when i checked in database nothing is displaying `> use import
Using database import
> precision rfc3339
> select * from import limit 3
>
`

Comment: Use this select * from oneyear.import

Comment: Sorry to bother you Shreeram, its not working `ERR: retention policy not found: oneyear`

Comment: Can you tell what's the measurement name which got created. Isn't "FO"